# delphi process XML using XSD

Tags: delphi, xml-parsing, xsd

I cannot seem to be able to access an online XML file contents using the XSD and XML Data Binding Wizard. I need to update daily a database table with all the requested currencies from an online XML.
I use Delphi XE and the XSD is located here:
http://www.bnr.ro/nbrfxrates.xsd
And the XML is this: http://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates2013.xml

So I downloaded the XSD, and processed it with XML Data Binding wizard. This resulted in the unit nbrfxrates.

I need to be able to access a rate for a specific currency at a specific date, some function like for example

```
function getMyRate(date,currency):double;
begin
...
end;
```

where I can provide a date and a currency and obtain the value from the XML.I have no idea how to do that.

The XML structure seems pretty simple but I am stuck at accessing it from Delphi...
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to load your file and access the nodes using the provided accessors, which are all basically Delphi standard classes with some magic to access the underlying DOM.

This is what I got after a couple of seconds of fiddling with your files.

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  obj: IXMLDataSet;
begin
  obj := LoadDataSet('D:\Downloads\nbrfxrates2013.xml');
  ShowMessage(obj.Body.Cube.Items[0].Date);
end;
```

Comment: Is there any way to access the XML directly on the web without downloading it first? It is located at http://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates2013.xml

Comment: Nothing accesses remote files without downloading them first. How do you think your web browser manages to display anything on the web?

Comment: Downloading a file from the net is easy. Drop an Indy HTTP component on your form, add `f := TFileStream.Create('D:\Downloads\nbrfxrates2013.xml', fmCreate);
IdHTTP1.Get('http://www.bnr.ro/files/xml/years/nbrfxrates2013.xml', f);f.Free;` before the code I provided, and you're set. Of course, it's up to you to add proper exception and error handling.